# How do you prove that a group of order 4 is Abelian if no element in it has order 4?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm interested in the case no element of G has order 4.  How do you prove that G(any arbitrary group of order 4) is abelian?

I realize that order of any element of G has to be either 1 (identity) or 2 (not identity) based on Lagrange's theorem.

Can't figure out the exact step of algebraic manipulation to go from ab to ba to show that ab=ba.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

Let a,b belong to G.  Since ab belongs to G (closure), (ab)(ab) = e.  Apply ba to both sides so get (ba)(ab)(ab) = (ba) e ==> baabab = ba ==> bebab = ba ==> eeab = ba ==> ab = ba

Answer (score 2):

If no element has order 4, every element has order 1 or 2 by Lagrange.  This is equivalent to each element being its own inverse.  Thus, given $a, b \in G$,
$$
ab = (ab)^{-1}= b^{-1}a^{-1}=ba.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let the elements be $1$, $a$, $b$ and $c$. Since no element has order $4$, all have order $1$ or $2$. Then the Cayley table starts off with
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c \\
a & 1 &   &   \\
b &   & 1 &   \\
c &   &   & 1
\end{array}
The product $ab$ must be $c$, because every element appears once in each row and column.
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c \\
a & 1 & c &   \\
b &   & 1 &   \\
c &   &   & 1
\end{array}
This allows to complete the rows and columns with three slot already determined
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c \\
a & 1 & c & b \\
b &   & 1 &   \\
c &   & a & 1
\end{array}
and so other rows and columns can be completed:
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c \\
a & 1 & c & b \\
b &   & 1 & a \\
c & b & a & 1
\end{array}
The last slot has to be $c$:
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & a & b & c \\
a & 1 & c & b \\
b & c & 1 & a \\
c & b & a & 1
\end{array}
The group is abelian.